# Can we pair two smart watches without a phone?

Tags: android-wear

As far as I know, wear smartwatches are designed to be companion devices that stay connected to your smartphone. Without a phone around, though, they aren't entirely useless.They'll still function as watches, for one, giving you the time and the date.

But I am not sure if there are any changes to this in any of the latest updates. So I want to know if it is possible to pair two smart watches and send messages using messageapi without the help of a smartphone. A lame question but I am very curios to know.

Ideally, I want two watches to interact using messageapi to send messages. Is it possible to do without a smartphone?

Answer (score 0):

No. Android Wear was designed to be used with a smartphone. Even if you did figure out how to do this it wouldn't have anywhere close to the amount of features it has now.